# Jenkins pipeline run on multiple slaves

Tags: jenkins

I have some work needs to run on two different slaves. The only example founs is this:

```
stages {
    parallel {
        stage('Test On slave1') {
            agent {
                label "slave1"
            }
            steps {
                sh "echo 'Hello from slave1'"
                ....
            }

        }
        stage('Test On slave2') {
            agent {
                label "slave2"
            }
            steps {
                sh "echo 'Hello from slave2'"
                ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the code is replicated for each slave.  Since the work is the same for all slaves, How can I define my work just one time a run on different slaves in parallel? Thanks.

Comment: Be it the blue or the red pill, welcome to the [matrix](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-matrix). 

Answer (score -1):

I find that I prefer a scripted pipeline implementation over declarative. It provides me a little more control and access to features of the groovy language.  One such feature is a closure.   In that scope, I would approach the issue similarly to what I have below.

```
#!groovy

//A map of String -> Closure that will be run in parallel
def parallelActions = [:]
parallelActions['agent1 test'] = newAgentAction('slave1')
parallelActions['agent2 test'] = newAgentAction('slave2')

stage ('running parallel actions') {
   parallel parallelActions
}

//Function builds common behavior and returns a closure (a function as an object)
def newAgentAction(agentLabel) {
  return { ->
      node (agentLabel) {
        echo "exectuting on ${agentLabel}"
      }
  }
}
```

Please note that I have intentionally not put the stage inside the parallel blocks. Depending on which plugins you're using for visualization having parallel stages can make the rendering order of stages unreliable and force constant stage redraws.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But... I have to use Groovy language just to run on two slaves? Incredible that "agent" or "node" directive does not support that.

Comment: I'm not sure that the declarative format does not support the parallel behavior, tbh.  This is simply how I've addressed it using the scripted syntax.